# Adding an export entry into dll file

Tags: dll

There is an dll file which i need to edit, Using PE Explorer option, Export Viewer i can see a long list of items and i suppose each entry is called "Export Function". Using notepad++ i can  access those items but since is a binary file any edit to it would lead to a crash. I have no knowledge in reverse engineering but i need to add several items into export table of this dll in order to remove the current limitation that i am stuck with. as i understand i must use a hex editor and first edit something called "ExportDirectory.NumberOfFunctions" which i am unable to find. Probably because i am looking in the wrong direction.

I understand there is no easy way to do this, so i am open to learning if is not possible to do this using any tools.

Regards

Comment: How would adding exports remove the limitation?

Comment: I have a game that comes with a folder containing all item files in it, the only way to add a new item is to remove current items by changing the content of any file in there. adding a new item file with a new name wont work since it seems is hard coded, i traced this to the dll file which contains all of item files name along with several code functions which i guess are used by game engine. i figure if i add more export functions i can bypass the limitation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently load a DLL to an executable](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21000/permanently-load-a-dll-to-an-executable)

Comment: This was indeed helpful, since this software allows me to edit export table. However the question deals with importing rather than exporting. I have played around with software and by editing number of function,number of names,address of function and address of names and oridinals i was able to add another entry but whenever i add the name it becomes n/a after saving, like this:"0x0250  0x0052F2BA n/a"
so new address stays but name is gone, so i must be doing something wrong regarding giving values. i increased all of names mentioned above by 4 except the last one.

Comment: I don't think it's a proper duplicate, albeit certainly related.